# Can RegEx have a conditional Expression depending on different Capture Groups?

Tags: regex

I have the following `URLs`:

```
www.domain.com/hello-username-world
www.domain.com/welcome-username-back
```

And have the following **RegEx** on the part after the `slash /`:

```
([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(world|back)
```

What I want to do is if the first group `([^-]+)` is `hello` then accept only `world` in the third group, and if it is `welcome` then then only `back`

Something like this **RegEx**:

```
((hello-([^-]+)-world)|(welcome-([^-]+)-back)|)
```

But without the need to define `first group` value, and making the `third group` depend on the `first group`'s value

is that possible using a single `RegEx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
[^\n]*?(?:(hello)|(welcome))[^\n]*(?(1)world|(?(2)back))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/39/),,, in which try matching and capturing `hello` or `welcome` and check pattern `world` or `back` respectively for the capturing result.

Comment: In this part `(?(1)world|(?(2)back))` correct me if I'm wrong, You check if first capture is true, If it is not, You check if the second capture is true, in case it wasn't `welcome` too, So this condition is `if (firstcapture = hello) then (world) elseif (firstcapture = welcome) then (back)` correct?

Comment: ok, it is.. For example, it is possible like this. `(?(n) (patternA)| (?(m) pattenB | (?(L) patternC | patternD ) ) )` . I think it's same statement in regex matching as `if n then pattenA elseif m then patternB elseif L then patternC else patternD`

Comment: What in case I wanted to refer to the result of the `capture group 2`? Do I refer to it by its numbers? like `world` would be `(3)` and `back` be `(4)` and build a condition over them? or the true of their parent group would be the `(3)` only?

Comment: It checks if correspond capture group was captured then matching pattern respectively

Comment: Capture group name is possible to the position instead of number like this.  (?(name)..)  https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/41/

Comment: Oh, Capturing by the name is a relieve, Makes it possible to capture a non-capture group.

Comment: Doesn't seem as I expected it, But can I make a condition on a non-captured group?

Comment: Why shoud you avoid `capturing` in using `conditional` ? It seems you read too much into capturing. Capture is just a capture. You can `ignore some values of captured after checking conditions` for your needs. That's it. And Please note that `spaces` of regex examples in my comments are placed for readability, so must remove `spaces` when using my regex examples. For more info about `conditional`, refer to https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html