# Building a Condition over a Non-Captured Group

Tags: regex

In the following **RegEx**:

```
((this)|(that))-((?(2)these|(?(3)those)))
```

I accept one of two cases:

- **this-these**
- **that-those**

for **this-these** I get the **Array** of :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => this-these 
    [1] => this 
    [2] => this 
    [3] => 
    [4] => these 
)
```

And for **that-those** I get the **Array** of :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => that-those 
    [1] => that 
    [2] => 
    [3] => that 
    [4] => those 
)
```

---

The Array resembles the **Caputred Groups**, What I want is to Capture only the Group of `these` and `those`, I don't want to pull any other Groups to get the Array of :

case of **this-these** :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => this-these 
    [1] => these 
)
```

case of **that-those** :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => that-those 
    [1] => those 
)
```

---

What I've tried was the following **RegEx**s:

```
(?:(this)|(that))-(?:(?(1)(these)|(?(2)(those))))
```

But got the **Array** of :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => that-those 
    [1] => 
    [2] => that 
    [3] => 
    [4] => those 
)
```

Then tried the **RegEx**:

```
(?:(?:this)|(?:that))-((?(1)(?:these)|(?(2)(?:those))))
```

Which was False because the Groups of `(1), (2)` doesn't exist.

How can I Capture a Non-Capture Group to Apply a Condition on it or Capture only the Groups I want only.

---

Additonal Case Would Be:

```
this-in-these
this-on-those

that-at-those
that-as-these
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey I would love to do that, But I'm trying to apply that over my previous question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49757342/9113120

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? This isn't possible in most of them.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm going to use it on htaccess URLs Rewrite Rules, I don't know which engine does it use, really.

Comment: That is impossible with your current approach. You need to capture `this` or `that` to use them in the conditional construct. BTW, what about [`(?:this|that)-((?<=this-)these|those)`](https://regex101.com/r/JPRgPq/1)?

Comment: htaccess allows PCRE type regex but it will help further to know what rewrite or redirect you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, this _is_ possible in almost all regex engines, but only if you're matching fixed strings (like in this example): `(these|those)(?:(?<=this-these)|(?<=that-those))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should post that as an answer and collect your upvotes. That's genius.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am not so sure, the real pattern may turn out more complicated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems perfect to be used, So it checks the previous value then applies the condition depending on it, Will add something in the question to check how it would be applied to it

Comment: @Toleo It will work only when the lookbehind pattern is fixed width *unless* you are using .NET or JavaScript in the latest Chrome versions, or PyPi regex in Python.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure it might not work in 100% of the cases, but as long as the patterns for `these` and `those` are distinguishable by a lookbehind, it's a great solution. I think it's useful enough that it deserves to be posted as an answer. (Besides, it looks like htaccess uses PCRE, so...)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I only use `PHP` currently with htaccess and PCRE, I added a multiple conditional example at the end of the question, The same RegEx can be applied on it?

Comment: I did not quite get the update: what are you trying to match there and why?

Comment: PCRE regex supports arbitrary expressions in lookbehinds, doesn't it? So Wiktor's regex should be able to handle whatever you throw at it?

Comment: `(?:this-[io]n|that-a[ts])-(these|those)` will match the 4 strings in the update - is that what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, Like this, I hope you put an Answer with all the effort you've made here in the comments so i can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it appears you do not even need any conditional constructs, nor lookbehinds.

You are looking for grouping constructs, a combination of a capturing and non-capturing group:

```
(?:this-[io]n|that-a[ts])-(these|those)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ABPlkM/1)

The `(?:this-[io]n|that-a[ts])-(these|those)` will

- `(?:this-[io]n|that-a[ts])` - match either `this-in`, `this-on`, `that-at` or `that as` (due to the *non-capturing group* `(?:...)`)
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(these|those)` - Capturing group 1: either `these` or `those`.

Your original problem could be solved with a lookbehind:

```
(?:this|that)-((?<=this-)these|those)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JPRgPq/1). However, in case the `this` or `that` patterns can vary, the regex might not work, as most regex engines do not supprt lookbehind patterns of unknown width unless you are using .NET or JavaScript in the latest Chrome versions, or PyPi regex in Python.

Here, `(?:this|that)` non-capturing group matches either `this` or `that`, then a hyphen is matched and then `these` is captured into Group 1 if the current location is preceded with `this-`, or `those` is captured otherwise.

Comment: Is there a `RegEx token` that can be used like the `lookbehind` But to check if a specific `word` exists? so instead of using `((?<=this-)these those)` we just check if the string contains `this` or `that` behind.

Comment: Do not use lookbehind, use `this-(these those)`, and what you need is in Group 1.

Comment: Yes, I understand, But was just wondering if that exists in `RegEx` overall, using the `conditinal statement` like  `(?(this\b)these|those)`